# Add file from string to new folder ZipArchive

Tags: php, zip

Lets say I have a variable called and instantiated:

`$css = 'body {color:red;}';`

Currently, I'm building my zip file as follows:

```
    ini_set("max_execution_time", 300);
    // create object
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    // open archive
    if ($zip->open("my-archive.zip", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
        die ("Could not open archive");
    }
    // initialize an iterator
    // pass it the directory to be processed
    $jsFiles  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("../js"));
    $cssFiles = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("../css"));
    $images   = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("../_design"));
    // iterate over the directory
    // add each file found to the archive
    foreach ($jsFiles as $key=>$value) {
        $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
    }
    foreach ($cssFiles as $key=>$value) {
        $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
    }
    foreach ($images as $key=>$value) {
        $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
    }
    // close and save archive
    $zip->close();
    echo "Archive created successfully.";
```

Lets say I already have a file called `color.css` located in `/css/main/color.css/` and I wanted my new string `$css` to replace this whole **NEW** file in the **archive**, how could I do that? I had a look at `ZipArchive::addFromString` but I could not see a way to put that in a certain folder. It's the only file that has to change in my whole directory.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at Example #2 at http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php you will see there that first parameter of ZipArchive::addFromString can actually be any path inside your zip archive.

Therefore in your case the call to  will look like this:

```
$zip->addFromString("css/main/color.css",$css);
```